# Fragments in android - when is the Activity that called them available?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Would this be correct :

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    private final Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    // use intent here and there
}
```

I know in servlets one must wait for init() to have the context available. What is the situation in android ? Do we have to do things like this in the `OnCreate` ? As an added question - is this kind of use of final fields frowned upon ? Does it mess up the lifecycle ?

Links welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this be correct :

No, as `getActivity()` will return `null` during the initialization step.

> What is the situation in android ?

`getActivity()` definitely returns the `Activity` in `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`, and later lifecycle methods. It may return the `Activity` in `onCreate()`, but I do not recall ever implementing `onCreate()` on a fragment, so I cannot say for certain.

> As an added question - is this kind of use of final fields frowned upon ?

Well, since this one will not work (see above), code crashes are generally frowned upon... :-)

Comment: Love this answer: "code that crashes is generally frowned upon".  Indeed.  I believe that getActivity will return an activity after onAttach()

Comment: It should be available _in_ the `onAttach` method. Still a link explaining all this in detail would be welcome ;)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: In terms of why your initializer won't work, that's because there is no `Context` passed into the constructor, and therefore no chance that the fragment can have a `Context` of any sort, let alone its activity. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment()

Comment: [so full of typos...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment())